# maximal convex patching in Computer graphics

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, graphics, 3d

Given a 3D object in Computer graphics, whose surface is represented as a 3D triangular mesh (mesh of 3D triangle objects), I need to find the maximum continual Convex patches on the surface of the given 3D object.

I am using OpenGl to render the graphics within a C++ program. What kind of methods or algorithms should I use to find the convex patches.

I have to apply different colors to the different convex patches on the object to signify the selection.

Say I have a sphere then the whole sphere is one maximal convex patch. Any portion of the sphere surface will be a convex patch, by maximal I mean the maximum continuous convex patch that can be found. Well in the rendering, depending on the viewing angles, the maximal convex patches visible to the viewer will have to colored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from any triangle. Traverse it's edge's and check that the angle between the two triangles is less than 180deg. If it is add it to the current selection and continue expanding.

The check is actually really simple if you use vector geometry. Say A - B  is the common edge with C on the selected side and D on the other. Then just check if `dot(cross((A-B), (D-B)), cross((A-B), (C-B)) < 0`.

Unfortunately OpenGL doesn't help with object algorithms. It only handles converting triangles to pixels.

Comment: `cross((A-B), (C-B))` is a vector parallel to the normal to triangle ABC, what's the logic behind checking the dot product of the above with edge D-B be -ve?

Comment: We should check the dot product of cross((A-B), (C-B)) and cross((A-B), (D-B))

Comment: i get it now, the normal to triangle ADB should be at a +ve acute angle with the normal to triangle ABC, and edge DB will be at 90 degrees to the normal to ADB, so angle between normal to ABC and edge DB should be in the range (90-180).
@Hellboy since cross product gives cos of the angle, Sorin's solution seems the best way to do it.

Comment: @sorin but that only works if normal to ABC, normal to ADB and edge DB all lie in the same plane, which is not necessary...

Comment: Ah, both the vectors parallel to the normals at B would be at 90 degrees with common edge AB, so they would lie in the same plane. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

> I need to do it using OpenGL

Then you're out of luck. OpenGL only **draws** points, lines and triangles. OpenGL is not a 3D modelling library, OpenGL is not a scene graph, OpenGL is not a graphics engine.

It does not do all purpose geometry processing (it may be possible to use a combination of geometry/tesselation shaders, transform feedback and compute shaders to do it, but it would be very cumbersome to implement).